# probelm in printing a list in python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, listview

Whenever I print a list of values in negative indexing in the console it shows only empty brackets. Whatever is the reason behind this problem [image: image is attached]

```
stu_information = ["name","roll_number","address","contact_information"]
print(stu_information[-1:-2])
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Your slice of list is always empty:

```
k = [1,2,3,4]

print( k[-1:-2] )  # this is an empty slice

print( k[-2:-1] )  # this is a non empty slice
```

You slice from -1 as start (`4`) to -2 as end (`3`) which you can not do unless you go backwards through the list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
#        -1
#     -2
#   -3
#-4
```

... slicing from -1 to -2 only works backwards ...

```
print( k[-1:-2:-1] )  # this is NOT an empty slice because you move backwards through it
```

Output:

```
[]
[3]   # the later index is not included 
[4]   #   hence only 1 output sliced
```